# Entity SQL (LINQ) after joining returning the data in incorrect order

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table `Columns` with two columns `ColumnId` and `ColumnName`:

[image]

I have another collection

```
List<int> cols = new List<int>() { 7, 1, 6, 2 }
```

This collection has the `ColumnId`s in a random fashion (not in order).

When I'm joining my `List<int>` collection with my database table, then the data is returned based on the order in the database table `Columns` - not as per the order in my collection i.e. the `List<int>`:

```
List<int> colIds = new List<int>(){7, 1, 6, 2};

var sql = from c in Columns
          join col in colIds on c.ColumnId equals col                           
          select c;

sql.Dump();
```

[image]

The result is as per the order in the database table not as per the order in the collection.

Comment: You didn't specify `OrderBy` (or `orderby`), why do you expect a particular order? In general the order of results of a query w/o `OrderBy` is undefined, i.e. could be anything.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I wanted the ordering based on my collection not as per table ordering. So order by c.ColumnId was not helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

Keeping my collection first and then joining it with the table fixed my order issue. With this, the result is based on the order in the collection not as per the joining table.

SQL that returns the correct order is as follows:

```
int[] colIds = new int[]{7, 1, 6, 2};

var sql = from col in colIds
    join c in Colums on col equals c.ColumnId           
    select new {c.ColumnId, c.ColumnName};

sql.Dump();
```

[image]